# Working with objects that are in a UICollectionView footer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with a bunch of cells, and one footer. In this footer, I have a button and label that I want to do things with (Change the text of the label, animate the button etc). So I tried making an outlet to my controller so I would work with these objects, but when I do, I get an error saying that i have an illegal Ccnfiguration: Connection cannot have a prototype object as its destination. Why is this? Is there any way to get around it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of connecting these UI elements via an `IBOutlet`, set a tag value for them in your NIB or storyboard file and refer to them using that value. For ex:

if you set the `UILabel` tag to 5

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


      UICollectionReusableView *footerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

      UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[footerView viewWithTag:5];
      label.text = //set text;

      return footerView;

}
```

As the code as well as your error suggests, the header and footer view along with the cells of a `UICollectionView`, are reused. `IBOutlet`s refer to a single object which is what was causing your problem.

Comment: This is the solution that helped me the most. In most cases of UICollectionView and UITableView, they're single section. So just set the tag to be the indexPath.item